# Prove $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}} = 1$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Another user [(Paramanand Singh)](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72031/paramanand-singh) suggested that: 
$$ \left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}- 1\right| = \frac{2|x|}{1+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}. $$

Starting from there, let $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$, so that $$|x|<\delta \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}<x+1<\frac{3}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{2}{3}<\frac{1}{x+1}<2. $$

Since $1+x>1+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}$, we have:

$$ \frac{2|x|}{1+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}} < \frac{2|x|}{1+x}<4|x|<4\delta. $$

Therefore, we need to pick $\delta = \min\left(\dfrac12, \dfrac{\epsilon}{4}\right).$

So, I have two questions:

1. How can I get $\frac{2|x|}{1+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ from $\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}- 1\right|$?
2. Is the $\delta$ I found correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You just need to multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1-x}+ \sqrt{1+x}$.
2. Your $\delta$ seems okay to me.

Comment: Thanks. How did I know I needed to multiply by $\sqrt{1-x}+ \sqrt{1+x}$ to get that nice form, though? That comes from experience or there's some pattern I should recognize?

Comment: It is just something that works. You will get a better sense of what you need to do as time goes by

Comment: @pbd: Notice that $\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}- 1\right| = \left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}\right|$.  Then, $\sqrt{1-x} + \sqrt{1+x}$ is the conjugate of the numerator.